# Failure in locating bowtie2 db for MetaPhlaAn2

Tags: python

I'm trying to run ConStrains algorithm from https://bitbucket.org/luo-chengwei/constrains.
I git cloned Constrains into $HOME. Then I ran the code and got an error message as follows :

---

[image: code and error message]

---

My metaphlan databases is located at

```
$HOME/metaphlan2/metaphlan_databases.
Line 586 of ConStrains.py
```

from the site https://bitbucket.org/luo-chengwei/constrains is giving me the errors. My PATH is shown below :

---

> /home/mathed/miniconda2/bin:/home/mathed/bin:/home/mathed/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/home/mathed/metaphlan2:/home/mathed/metaphlan2/utils:/home/mathed/repos/bowtie2.

---

How can I locate it? Thank you.

Comment: As I understand, you have to run the script within `$HOME/metaphlan2/metaphlan_databases`.

Comment: Thank you @stovfl, I've fixed the issue. But I'd encountered another problem. When I ran mathed@mathed-XPS-8910:~/metaphlan2/metaphlan_databases$ python ConStrains.py -c ./config -out

Project info saved to: ut/proj.log
Now constructing SNP flows...
[FATAL]: Failure in locating mpa.pkl for MetaPhlAn2. I put my mpa.pkl at /home/mathed/mataphlan2/mataphlan_databases and at /home/mathed/metaphlan2/mataphlan_databases/db but gives the same message. Can you help me on this? Thank you.

Comment: Assuming `metaphlan2.py` are in `/home/mathed/metaphlan2`, the `.pkl` file have to go in on of `/home/mathed/metaphlan2/db_v*/`.

Comment: @stovfl Thank you very much! You've solved my problem. Thank you for your time and support.